# Is it possible to monitor or change the system audio volume in Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, air, adobe, volume

I am making a game in AS3 / Adobe AIR that requires the user to react to certain sounds. Is there a way to inform the user up front if the system volume is muted? Moreover, is there a method to change the volume? If not, does an external cross-platform application exist that lets me monitor the volume and that I can call from Adobe AIR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only access you may have to sound volum is restricted to the application (Flash player or AIR). You can change it with `SoundMixer.soundTransform.volume` for the general volume or `SoundChannel.soundTransform.volume` for a specific sound.

To summerize, you can't access the OS sound manager's settings or state with Flash. That's why many flash websites start with a message asking the users to switch their speakers on.

Comment: If you're capable of native development, you can create an AIR extension that, if available on your platform(s) of choice, can change the volume for you.

Comment: Good idea Tegeril! But I don't see the point of trying to solve this problem anyway, you won't ever be able to tell if the speakers are on, the volume of the speakers is high, the headphones are on the user's ears...

Comment: Definitely agreed, more effort than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Native Extensions is the way to go.

You can follow an Adobe tutorial: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html

Or download them ready made: https://github.com/nweber/SystemVolumeNativeExtension